# Pass props to a slot from the Child with Vue

Tags: vue.js

I've been thinking on passing a prop content to a slot from the child

This is my solution:

```html
<div id="app">

  <example>
    <template #example-body="{ exampleText }">
      <p>{{ exampleText }}</p>
    </template>
  </example>
  
</div>
```

```js
Vue.component('example', {
  data () {
    return {
      exampleText: "This is a sample"
    }
  },
  
  template: `
    <div>
      <slot name="example-body" v-bind:exampleText="exampleText" />
    </div>`
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

https://codepen.io/sirlouen/pen/OJWMRba

It works, but I don't feel it's enough elegant.

How could I improve it?

In fact, if I'm sincere, I don't understand why this works. I've been testing like a hundred options until I made it work, but not sure why, specially the { } within the template.

If someone could provide me more info it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally you've :

```
<template #example-body="slotProps">
  <p>{{ slotProps.exampleText }}</p>
</template>
```

but we could destruct that object which is ES6 syntax :

```
<template #example-body="{ exampleText }">
  <p>{{ exampleText }}</p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was looking for

```html
<div id="app">

  <example>
    <template #example-body="slotProperties">
      <p>{{ slotProperties.passedExample }}</p>
    </template>
  </example>
  
</div>
```

```js
Vue.component('example', {
  data () {
    return {
      exampleText: "This is a sample"
    }
  },
  
  template: `
    <div>
      <slot name="example-body" v-bind:passedExample="exampleText" />
    </div>`
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

https://codepen.io/sirlouen/pen/GRroOBv

As I mentioned in the comments above, what I did not had clear, was the relationship between the binded element in the slot and the result in the HTML.

What I've found strange and interesting, is that the `passedExample` prop is part of an object from the slot, not the variable itself.